# What is the role of owner parameter in airflow operator

Tags: airflow

In Airflow documentation [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/baseoperator/index.html) the `owner` parameter is described as following:

> owner (str) – the owner of the task, using the unix username is
> recommended

I don't understand the meaning of "owner of the task".

Is it the name of user that run this task? like an owner of a file?

If this is really a user name, how can it be that I use a name of user that not exist and didn't get any error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Owner can be anything. It is used to classify your DAGs in Airflow. For eg. You have 5 DAGs each processing data from SQL server you can use owner name for those DAGs as sql server and if you have 2 DAGs processing data from BigQuery you can give owner name as bigquery. In general you can assume that an owner name is used to identify to whom the DAG belongs to. It can even be your name.